# Вылезла ошибка с4700

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

```
IN In::checkIn(IN& in)
{
    unsigned char *checkText = in.text;
    unsigned char *newText;
    unsigned short index=0,temp=0,k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen((char*)checkText); i++) {        
    if (checkText[i] == ' ') {
            if (k == 0) continue;
            if (checkText[i] == ' ') continue;
        }
    newText[k] = checkText[i];
    k++;
    }
return in;
}
```

Данная функция должна записывать в строку `newText` строку `checkText` без пробелов. Но при компиляции вылазит

> Ошибка C4700   использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "newText".

Как тогда её инициализировать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что такое у вас `newText`? Судя по всему, строка. **Куда** вы хотите писать ваши `unsigned char` вот здесь?

```
newText[k] = checkText[i];
```

Сейчас - в некоторое случайное место в памяти.

А как инициализировать? Сделать так, чтоб она указывала на *корректное, нужное вам* место в памяти. Я же не могу знать, что вы хотите, *смысл* ваших действий... Может, надо выделить память динамически, может, передать указатель через аргумент функции - это решаете вы.

Чтоб компилятор просто заткнулся и не кричал, достаточно

```
unsigned char *newText = nullptr;
```

но, думаю, вы понимаете, что это глупое решение :)

Comment: не очень доходчиво для новычков(ИМХО)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Если понимаете, как - подправьте, pls.

Comment: просто думаю, что ТС не понимает почему это глупое решение и сколько у него логических ошибок, и как  вообше добиваться правильного результата

Answer (score 0):

почему бы просто не использовать класс string 
Ответ выше звучит исчерпывающе) вы создаете указатель unsigned char *newText;
но не инициализируйте его (оно не инициализируется NULL по умолчанию) выходит ссылается на случайный участок памяти. Вам необходимо направить это на какой либо массив в случае хранения данных количество которых не превышает strlen((char*)checkText)
можно просто .... код не совсем понятен для чего вам вообще нужен вы делаете в него как бы запись но в логике это не используется ... мне кажется у вас немного страдает архитектура функции.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны были инициализировать указатель. наверняка он должен указывать на массив имеющий достаточный размер для помещения текста без пробелов. Но у вас не только ошибка компиляции, а вся логика  кода. Долго рассказывать что и почему неправильно, я просто покажу как легче добиться этого без дополнительных массивов и указателей, т.е. как убрать пробелы из массива символов:

```
IN In::checkIn(IN& in)
{
    const size_t size = strlen(in.text);    
    size_t k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (in.text[i] != ' ') {
           in.text[k++] = in.text[i];           
        }
    }   
    //и поставим завершающий символ в свое место
    in.text[k] = '\0';  
    //если для массива выделена память из кучи, 
    //и память критична, то можно выделить новую
    //копировать, а потом удалять старый
    return in;
}
```